# How adjust the Vaadin components' vertical alignment in a HorizontalLayout?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to align the Button on the same line as the Text Fields. The item alignment has been set to `Alignment.CENTER`, but as you can see from the image, the vertical centers of the TextFields are lower due to the label on top of them.

```
    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    horizontalLayout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
    Div div = new Div(buttonAddPriceRange);
    horizontalLayout.add(spanneVon, spanneBis, div);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`layout.setAlignItems(Alignment.BASELINE);` allows you to align items by the baseline, that is with the bottom.

[image: Textfield and button baseline aligned]

```java
HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout(new TextField("hello"),
    new Button("world"));
hl.setAlignItems(Alignment.BASELINE);
add(hl);
```

Check out the great video [Master Vaadin VerticalLayout and HorizontalLayout - layouts in Vaadin Flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efv_cPHEqdQ) to learn more.

Answer (score 4):

Try ...

`horizontalLayout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.BASELINE);`